TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out
I have a system where many users connect to a database SQL Server through an application, everything works as it should, but sometimes, very rarely, an error occurs.

Message: A network or instance-specific error occurred while
establishing a connection to SQL Server.The server was not found or
was not accessible.Verify that the instance name is correct and that
SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.(Provider: TCP
Provider, Error: 0 - Operation timed out.)

The error is not widespread, it occurs randomly once or twice a month for one of any users, after the error occurs the user tries to connect to the database again and everything works, while all other sessions work, sessions are not disconnected for working users.
I can’t catch and understand the reason for the error, please tell me who has had this happen.
I thought that there were problems with the network, I configured tcping on ports 1433 and 1434 from client machines to SQL Server, but I did not find any losses, I read that people write about such problems if there is a lack of RAM, but my server is powerful and there seem to be no memory drawdowns .

Name resolution timeout, perhaps? Does the error occur if you configure the connection(s) to use the server IP address instead of name?

This definitely smells like a network problem, not a database one.

@mustaccio
Specifying IP address in the connection line is the second step that we are going to check, so far we have bypassed the DNS by specifying the resolution in the local hosts file, but problems also arise. I'm glad that you are from Ukraine, so am I

@J.D.
I also believe that there is a problem with the network, but I need some evidence in order to contact the network service, I do not have the knowledge and tools to track it down this problem. So I ask for help in this matter.
